# Use UTF-8 with BOM in Xcode

Tags: xcode, utf-8

In a cross-platform workflow, I need to keep sources files in **UTF-8 with BOM** encoding.

When I'm editing these files in Xcode, it opens these files in UTF-8 *without* BOM, stripping it from file when I save it.

UTF-8 with BOM is not available in encoding drop-down list in Xcode preferences.

Is there a way to force the use of UTF-8 with BOM in Xcode?

Comment: Maybe you should consider the other way: in a cross-platform you should not use UTF-8 with BOM (BOM doesn't belong to UTF-8, as Unicode standard recommend). For this reason you will find that nearly all programs (but few of Microsost (but inconsistently) and some done for Windows uses (incorrectly) BOM

Comment: We encountered problems with UTF-8 without BOM on some IDE or compiler. Android Studio also complains with Windows-1252 files, forcing us to use UTF-8. To avoid conflicts between these two encodings, we decided to use UTF-8 with BOM. All worked fine, before using Xcode.

Comment: It is mostly useless. Use UTF-8 everywhere, and if it gives you errors, it is cp1252. Also the web works in such manner. It is practically impossible to have a valid cp1252 (with sensible content) which it is also valid UTF-8 (but for pure ASCII files, so it doesn't matter which encoding). Most editors know this. So probably you are trying to fix a non-issue. (aka: instead of checking if it has a BOM, check if it is valid UTF-8)